# How to show $u_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}\vert x-r_k \vert^{-\alpha}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $W^{1,p}(U)$?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In Chapter 5 (Sobolev Spaces) of *Partial Differential Equations (2nd Edition)* by Evans, Example 4 says the following:

> Let $\{r_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a countable, dense subset of $U=B^0(0,1)$. Write
> $$ u(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\vert x-r_k \vert^{-\alpha}, \quad x\in U $$
> Then $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$ for $\alpha <\frac{n-p}{p}$.

I am having trouble proving that $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$. I have tried looking at the partial sum $$u_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}\vert x-r_k \vert^{-\alpha}$$ and attempt to show that $(u_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $W^{1,p}(U)$. However, I am not able to make any progress in showing that $(u_n)$ is indeed a Cauchy sequence. Any advice on how I can show that this gives a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: I think the questions was already answered, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502134/evans-pde-example-4-p-260-clarification?rq=1

Comment: @Velobos I don't think that post mentioned $(u_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Also, the proof made me feel a little iffy as he went from $\int_U u_k(x) dx < \infty$ to $\sup_k\int_U u_k(x) dx < \infty$, which I'm not too sure that's how supremum over $k\in\mathbb{N}$ works given that $(u_k)$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Try to bound $||\partial_i(u_r-u_q)||_{L^p(U)}^p$ using the Integral Minkowski inequality in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502134/evans-pde-example-4-p-260-clarification?rq=1. Then try to bound the following quantity that should appears : $\int_{U} \frac{x_i}{|x-r_k|^{(\alpha+1)p} }dx$ independently of $k$, using for exemple the change of variables $y=x-r_k$.